# Getting a "Bad Request" for a GetFileByServerRelativePath/CopyTo for creating a SharePoint Page from a Template

Tags: json, sharepoint, http-headers, httprequest, sharepoint-online

I created a flow that would create a new page from items inputted into a SharePoint list.

The first step is supposed to copy a template file and post it as a new page using the List Item's title name.

My inputs are as follows:

```
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_sharepointonline",
        "operationId": "HttpRequest"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/KSDTestSite",
        "parameters/method": "POST",
        "parameters/uri": "_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(‘/sites/KSDTestSite/SitePages/Templates/KSD-Template.aspx’)/copyTo(‘/sites/KSDTestSite/SitePages/Microsoft_Security_Update_and_EOL_Notification.aspx')",
        "parameters/headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    }
}
```

and the Outputs:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=fa5ce4b13622b0d3617b4398e823c470b20f49c8905d33671c1e72b454b4c01b;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-ncus.azconn-ncus-001.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=fa5ce4b13622b0d3617b4398e823c470b20f49c8905d33671c1e72b454b4c01b;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-ncus.azconn-ncus-001.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "x-ms-request-id": "86e9b9a0-403e-3000-ac9a-13008bc3168f",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",
        "Date": "Mon, 05 Jun 2023 16:37:17 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "750",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Expires": "-1"
    },
    "body": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "The expression \"web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(‘/sites/KSDTestSite/SitePages/Templates/KSD-Template.aspx’)/copyTo(‘/sites/KSDTestSite/SitePages/Microsoft_Security_Update_and_EOL_Notification.aspx')\" is not valid.\r\nclientRequestId: 5b37d689-d8b9-439f-af4f-2005d6b07e0d\r\nserviceRequestId: 86e9b9a0-403e-3000-ac9a-13008bc3168f",
        "source": "https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/KSDTestSite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(%E2%80%98/sites/KSDTestSite/SitePages/Templates/KSD-Template.aspx%E2%80%99)/copyTo(%E2%80%98/sites/KSDTestSite/SitePages/Microsoft_Security_Update_and_EOL_Notification.aspx')",
        "errors": [
            "-1",
            "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
        ]
    }
}
```

I keep running into this "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException" error, which I've seen it could be a permissions issue? But its a dev environment and there are really no permissions to speak of. Anyways, if anyone has any idea, it would be greatly appreciated.

[HTTP Request to SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl9hW.png)

Full Error Page [image: Full Error Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you find by yourself, there was an issue with quotes in the URI:

**‘** was used instead of **'**

Correct syntax is:

```
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_sharepointonline",
        "operationId": "HttpRequest"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/KSDTestSite",
        "parameters/method": "POST",
        "parameters/uri": "_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath('/sites/KSDTestSite/SitePages/Templates/KSD-Template.aspx')/copyTo('/sites/KSDTestSite/SitePages/Microsoft_Security_Update_and_EOL_Notification.aspx')",
        "parameters/headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    }
}
```

For security purpose, I remove your tenant root URL.
Feel free to edit your question and blur your screenshot as well.